# Check Available page file size

Tags: .net, memory, memory-management, paging

My page size is set 10 gb, I would like to use .net api's to find out if the available page size is less than 25 % (i.e 2.5 gb ) , in which case I would like to kill processes.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at `System.Diagnostics.Process.PagedMemorySize64`, this property will tell you how much paged memory your process is using. If you have a hard cap, just calculate your current usage vs. that cap and kill the process if necessary.